# I am trying to populate a table with a number that increments

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to keep track of how many times someone has flipped a coin and which side it was.

I do not understand how to get the number to increment itself nor get the table to get the row to populate with the div result appropriately. There is a space between the first instance and the second where it does not record heads or tails.

**HTML**

```
<button id="flip" type="button" onclick="addRow()">Flip the coin</button>
  <div id="result"></div>

  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <th>Flips</th>
      <th>Results</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      
    </tr>
    <tr>
      
    </tr>
  </table>
```

**Script for Coin Flip**

```
let button = document.getElementById("flip");
let result = document.getElementById("result");

function fnClick(event) {
  let num = Math.random();

  if (num < 0.5) {
    result.innerHTML = "You got HEAD";
  } else {
    result.innerHTML = "You got TAIL";
  }
}
```

**Script For New Row**

```
function addRow() {
  var number = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    number++;
    console.log(number);
  }
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell1.innerHTML = i;
  cell2.innerHTML = result.innerHTML;
}
button.addEventListener("click", fnClick);
```

I would like to add a number to the left of my table progressively as the user clicks the coin flip as well as keep track of the results on the right side of the table.
How do I do this?

Comment: What's the point of the `for` loop in `addRow()`?

Comment: Use a global variable for the counter that you increment every time you flip a coin.

Comment: I am attempting to add an increment to the the number and I thought that a for loop would be able to do the trick.

Comment: Maybe you should be creating the rows inside the loop?

Comment: Your loop is just equivalent to `number = 10000`, except that it logs all the 10,000 numbers before that first.

Comment: Make `number` a global variale and then just do `number++` to increment it.

Comment: Thank you! Making the number a global variable did the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your addRow function like this and move the number variable outside to make it global

```js
 var number = 0;
function addRow() {
  number++;
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var row = table.insertRow(0);
  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  cell1.innerHTML = number;
  cell2.innerHTML = result.innerHTML;
}
button.addEventListener("click", fnClick);
```

Comment: thank you! this fixed my problem. I am still having trouble displaying the result.innerHTML in the proper place. 

The rows look like this 
3 TAILS
2 HEADS
1 ______
with nothing on the first row

Comment: check how your functions are written fnClick and addRow. Check if fnClick is written above addRow function.

Comment: I switched them so that addRow is above fnClick but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Comment: add all the code inside fnClick in the start of add row function and remove button.addEventListener("click", fnClick); from code

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
<table id="myTable">
    <th>
        <th>Flips</th>
        <th>Results</th>
    </th>
</table>
```

JS Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    let button = document.getElementById("flip");
    let result = document.getElementById("result");

    function fnClick(event) {
        let num = Math.random();
        let side = "HEAD";

        if (num < 0.5) {
            result.innerHTML = "You got HEAD";
            side = "HEAD";
        } else {
            result.innerHTML = "You got TAIL";
            side = "TAIL";
        }

        addRow(num, side);
    }

    function addRow(num, side) {
        var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
        var row = table.insertRow(0);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell1.innerHTML = num;
        cell2.innerHTML = side;
    }
    button.addEventListener("click", fnClick);
</script>
```